# Non-blocking FileWalkTree file search with Webflux

Tags: java

I need to create a non-blocking functionality where I search text files within a given folder and it returns the count of search terms found in it.

I am able to execute the test in a blocking manner. I am wondering if anyone could help me transform it into a non-blocking task so that whenever a file is finished being scanned the result delivered without waiting for all the files to be scanned.

The main point is: I don't want to wait for all files to be scanned to start delivering the result to the client (Angular app).

```
public interface SearchService {
    List<SearchResponse> search(SearchRequest searchRequest);
}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ToString
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class SearchResponse implements Serializable {

    private final String server;
    private final String filePath;
    private final long count;
    private final boolean errorReadingFile;
}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;


@ToString
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class SearchRequest implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    private final String server;
    @NotNull
    private final String rootPath;
    @NotNull
    private final String searchTerm;
}
```

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;


@Slf4j
@Service
public class FileSearchService implements SearchService {

    @Override
    public List<SearchResponse> search(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
        Path start = Paths.get(searchRequest.getRootPath());
        EnumSet<FileVisitOption> opts = EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
        int maxDepth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        SearchTermFileVisitor visitor = new SearchTermFileVisitor(searchRequest, new ArrayList<>());
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(start,opts,maxDepth, visitor);
            return visitor.getSearchResponseList();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Slf4j
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SearchTermFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private final SearchRequest searchRequest;
    private final List<SearchResponse> searchResponseList;

    private SearchResponse searchFileContent(Path path, SearchRequest searchRequest) {
        SearchResponse response;
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            response = SearchResponse.of(
                    searchRequest.getServer(),
                    Paths.get(path.toUri()).toString(),
                    countWordsInFile(searchRequest.getSearchTerm(), br.lines()),
                    false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = SearchResponse.of(
                    searchRequest.getServer(),
                    path.toString(),
                    0,
                    true);
        }
        log.debug(response.toString());
        return response;
    }

    private int countWordsInFile(String searchTerm, Stream<String> linesStream) {
        return linesStream
                .parallel()
                .map(line -> countWordsInLine(line, searchTerm))
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }

    private int countWordsInLine(String line, String searchTerm) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line.toLowerCase());

        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find(i)) {
            count++;
            i = matcher.start() + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

    private boolean isTextFile(Path path) throws IOException {
        String type = Files.probeContentType(path);
        if (type == null) {
            //type couldn't be determined, assume binary
            return false;
        } else if (type.startsWith("text")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            //type isn't text
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
        log.debug("Visited: " + (Path) dir);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (attrs.isRegularFile()
                && !attrs.isDirectory()
                && !attrs.isSymbolicLink()
                && isTextFile(file)) {
            searchResponseList.add(searchFileContent(file, searchRequest));
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

The test case:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

class FileSearchServiceTest {

    private SearchService searchService = new FileSearchService();

    @Test
    void test_search_window_root_c_path() {
        SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of("localhost", "c:\\", "a");
        final List<SearchResponse> searchResult = searchService.search(sr);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(searchResult.size());
    }
}
```

I want to use WebFlux to receive the results one by one without waiting for all the files to be scanned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider (1) performing the search in a separate thread, (2) using the observer pattern for receiving intermediate results back to the thread created code (references below), and (3) join the search thread to the implementing code so you can return the result list once it is finished.  It means you need to pass 'this' to the thread so it has a reference to call back to a separate method for intermediate results.  The references below contain sample code.

Think of this like a GUI.  You can run the GUI in a separate thread, and for every button click it calls back to the controller code (including a 'finish' once Exit is clicked).

Re:  https://dzone.com/articles/the-observer-pattern-using-modern-java
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for your answer. I have solved my problem using Google Guava.
Yo can check my work here : https://github.com/ffroliva/mimecast-backend